# Onion skinning stopped working

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm working on a 2d animation using the grease pencil, I keep running into  a problem with the onion skinning function.

It has worked at points, So it definitely has to do with my actions. I just don't know what it is specifically. There was a point where it corrected itself but now it has resurfaced as a problem.

I have checked similar forums but with no success. I have onion skinning enabled in both summary and overlay. I do have multiple grease strokes, I don't know if that is the factor. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Please let me know what other info you might need...

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my answer, I need to enable view in render, under display, in the onion skinning tab in object data properties

Answer (score 0):

The solution is frustratingly simple: Press the Show Overlays button.
I had the same problem, too, and I only just found the answer.
(The Show overlays button is at the top, next to the viewport display type. When on, it's blue.)